# Возможно ли сделать автообновление локальных Docker образов в TestContainers, используя класс DockerComposeContainer?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В docker-compose файле у меня несколько разных сервисов, все они со статичным тэгом "latest" (например: "some_image1:latest", "some_image2:latest", ну и так далее). Перед прогоном автотестов я хочу проверять образы на наличие изменений и, если изменения есть, обновлять только измененные образы. Я пока не понял как это сделать, потому сейчас перед каждым запуском я просто удаляю все локальные образы и заново подкачиваю все, не делая какие-нибудь предварительные проверки. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
object TestEnvironment {

    fun start() {
        environment.stop()
        environment.start()
    }

    private val environment: KDockerComposeContainer =
        KDockerComposeContainer(ResourceUtils.getResourceAsFile("/docker/docker-compose.yml"))
            .withLocalCompose(true)
            .withRemoveImages(DockerComposeContainer.RemoveImages.ALL)
            ...
            ...
}
```

Строка `.withRemoveImages(DockerComposeContainer.RemoveImages.ALL)` удаляет все локальные образы.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна опция [withPull](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.12.1/org/testcontainers/containers/DockerComposeContainer.html#withPull-boolean-):

```
private val environment: KDockerComposeContainer =
        KDockerComposeContainer(ResourceUtils.getResourceAsFile("/docker/docker-compose.yml"))
            .withLocalCompose(true)
            .withPull(true)
            ...
            ...
```

Когда она установлена, `testcontainers` выполнит `docker-compose pull`, который в свою очередь сделает `docker pull` для задействованных образов. Эта команда обновит измененные образы перед запуском.

Comment: Не. WithPull() устанавливает значение переменной pull в DockerComposeContainer. Оно по дефолту true. И оно так не работает. Возможно, данный параметр спасает, когда тэг это изменяемый номер версии, а не статичное имя тэга.

Comment: pull работает именно так как нужно и для статического имени тега. Вот даже в доке есть про pull policy - это аналог опции pull (https://www.testcontainers.org/features/advanced_options/). Когда-то боролся с этой проблемой, и она была именно в том, что pull не делался (правда это было в testcontainers для python, там это вообще не было реализовано). Если вы действительно уверенны, что pull по умолчанию true, то не знаю. Думаю, у вас скорее проблема в том, что docker-compose не пересоздает контейнеры. Удаление образов вам помагает, потому что в этом случае и контейнеры удаляются.

Comment: Нет. Контейнеры пересоздаются. Проблема в другом. В DockerComposeContainer pull работает по-своему. Он пуллит только в том случае, если images недоступны локально. Это описано в классе DockerClientFactory над методом checkAndPullImage. Потому я сейчас и удаляю все сразу.

Comment: Проверил - в testcontainers на питоне все реализовано через docker-compose. В java все по другому и еще и в разных версях по разному. Какую версию testcontainers вы используете? Если в целом, то это еще не реализовано https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4601. Есть вот https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/4662 то что вам нужно, но это не совместимо с тем, что сейчас в мастере. Добавить, кстати в мастер, это довольно легко, там используется RemoteDockerImage, который pullPolicy поддерживает напрямую, нужно только добавить параметр и прокинуть его.

Comment: прокинуть в https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/DockerComposeContainer.java#L207

Comment: У меня ща 1.16.2 версия. Ну, пока накостылим что-нибудь пока сами и подождем обнову. Спасибо